# Stream Audio from internal Microphone to 3.5mm headphone jack

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder

I have a simple Question :

How can i turn an Android Device into a Modern Microphone ? ,

I does no want to Record Audio , i just want :

1. Speak
2. Audio is Forwarded to the 3.5 Jack Output(No Input) where a Speaker is Connected for example ,

Thanks .

Edit : Here is the Code i am using , Thanks to everyone who contributed here and Thanks @user1917769 for your working Answer , i have no Any Lag its work fine as a real Mic Device :

```
 import android.media.AudioFormat;
 import android.media.AudioManager;
 import android.media.AudioRecord;
 import android.media.AudioTrack;
 import android.media.MediaRecorder;
 import android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource;
 import android.util.Log;

 public class TOne extends Thread {
 private Thread T1;
 private byte audiobuffer[] = new byte[20];
 public boolean Okay = true;
 public AudioRecord a;
 public AudioTrack aud;
 private static int[] mSampleRates = new int[] { 8000, 11025, 22050, 44100 };
 @Override
 public void run() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //super.run();
int i=AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000 , AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO ,      AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
a= findAudioRecord();

if(a.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED){
   a= findAudioRecord();  
 }
  a.startRecording();
    Log.e("Play Audio" , "Start");

 aud = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,8000,
         AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,   AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
     AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT),AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

 if(aud.getState() != AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED){
aud = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,8000,
         AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,      AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
         AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT),AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

 }
          aud.play();
         while(Okay){


                 a.read(audiobuffer,0,audiobuffer.length);

                        ////Log.e("IS_ACTIVE", "YES");
                         aud.write(audiobuffer,0,audiobuffer.length);



 }



 }


 public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {

for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
    for (short audioFormat : new short[] { AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT,      AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT }) {
        for (short channelConfig : new short[] { AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,      AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO }) {
            try {
                Log.d("C.TAG", "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat +      ", channel: "
                        + channelConfig);
                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate,      AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO , AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

                if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 8000,      channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                    if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                        return recorder;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("C.TAG", rate + "Exception, keep trying.",e);
            }
        }
    }
}
return null;
 }

 private void LetsPlayThatsAudio() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub







 }


 }
```

But i am thinking to put this into a Service wich implements a Thread so i can Start/Stop easily

Comment: There will be some latency if you do this, which could amount to up to a couple of 100 milliseconds, depending on the device and Android version used. There's no way (at least for an app) to create a direct loopback from an audio input to an audio output.

Comment: Ok , thanks for your Note , i am going to try the Suggested answer ...

Comment: Rolled back 3rd party edit - the subject of the question is streaming, not redirection, as there is normally no input-output path - it must be created, not re-routed.

Comment: I'm looking for some piece of code for my karaoke app, does your code has any latency from your voice to the speaker? I will try it tomorrow! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this you will have to first record sound from mobile microphone and then play it on your phone at the same time.for recording work try this in thread 1 and get data in audiobuffer byte array

```
        int i=AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCO DING_PCM_16BIT);
        AudioRecord a= new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,8000,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,i);
        a.startRecording();
        byte audiobuffer[]=new byte[20];
        new thread2().start();
        while(true)
        {
             a.read(audiobuffer,0,audiobuffer.length);
        }
```

at the same time for playing that data that will output sound to 3.5 mm jack try this code
in thread 2

```
 AudioTrack aud= new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,8000,
 AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,       AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT),AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
 aud.play();
while(true)
{ 
    aud.write(audiobuffer,0,audiobuffer.length);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i Agree with @Chris Stratton & What is the difference using MediaRecorder & MediaPlayer ? so there is no need to Write Audio to a File then Play it using this way , Thread One to Receive Audio , & Thread 2 to Play Audio Received in Thread One

Comment: As long as both calls use the same sample clock, and the code beneath the APIs is sane about internal buffering, you can just call the read method of the input and the write method of the output in sequence in a loop within a single thread.  Note however that you will likely have a noticeable delay from input to output, depending a bit on buffer size... trying to talk through it (if you can hear the output) may prove extremely difficult.

Comment: start thread2 from thread1 as in my edited code.Both threads will be in same class.They will use same byte array class variable.Additional to this you dont need anything extra for synchronisation.I used two threads for minimising delay for playing that data.

Comment: So i need to Record/Play into the same Thread Class ? because aud.write(audiobuffer,0,audiobuffer.length); will be null if i have Two separated Thread Class Right ?

Comment: Sorry, but *persisting* in recommending broken threading earns this a -1

Comment: try sleep method before while loop in thread2 to pause it for sometime,after that audiobuffer will be filled with data.

Comment: @user1917769 Yes , i have no Force Close when i uses Sleep Method but there is no Audio Played(Blank) , when i remove the Sleep Method , i have a Force Close with Error "play() called on uninitialized audiotrack" , Both(Record/Play) are in the same Thread & i have declared this as Global Variable : "private byte audiobuffer[] = new byte[20];"

Comment: post your code,error and also if possible try using two threads as I said before.

Comment: @user1917769 , my New Question now is How can i Stop the Thread/Audio Streaming when pressing Back or leaving the Activity , this is a Background Thread Class , Thanks (Tested on a Samsung Galaxy S4 Android 4.2.2 - Cyanogen Mod)

Comment: i have posted the Working code by editing this Answer but it was removed

Comment: write your code inside while loop checking a boolean as condition.Write that boolean false when you want to stop.Additional to this also take a look at AsyncTask.